# Subset with [ ] or subset( ) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I was working with a dataframe similar to this one, called **DB_reduced**:

| sex | BLT | BLN | BD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f | NA | 45 | 2 |
| f | 3 | 46 | NA |
| m | 3.5 | NA | 1 |
| f | 4 | 43 | 1 |
| NA | 3.4 | 46 | 3 |
| f | 3.4 | 46 | 3 |
| NA | 3.6 | 41 | 3 |

I was expected to get a similar result with this two codes:

```
DB_reduced[DB_reduced$sex == "f", 2] # first line
# or
subset(DB_reduced, DB_reduced$Sexo == "f", select = 2, drop = TRUE) # second line
```

but rather than just finish with the same dataframe, the first returns:

```
sex  BLT
f    NA
f    3
f    4
NA   3.4
f    3.4
NA   3.5
```

and the second:

```
sex  BLT
f    NA
f    3
f    4
f    3.4
```

Why the difference? I thought that both codes worked in tha same way.
How can I modify the first line to obtain the same result as the second?

Thanks all!

Comment: You can change the first line to `DB_reduced[DB_reduced$sex == "f" & !is.na(DB_reduced$sex), 2]`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `?subset` specifies the following:

```
subset  logical expression indicating elements or rows to keep: missing values are taken as false.
```

so it drops `NA`s by default. You can get the same result using `[` by adding `& !is.na(DB_reduced$sex)` as noted in the comments.

Comment: Yes, but what can I do with the first line (DB_reduced[DB_reduced$sex == "f", 2] ) to also drop NAs?

Comment: @MJRC See my edit and MrFlick's comment under your question.